# How to Place Connections Between Microblaze and Custom RTL Modules in Vivado

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vivado

I am very confused with this particular issue and would appreciate any help.

So I am using the Vivado block design to place a Microblaze with 128kB local memory modules, an AXI GPIO and UartLite modules and a clocking wizard (and some reset controller Vivado adds similar to the local memory). Using the basys 3 FPGA development board.

I have created a basic custom RTL called top that instantiates some basic components (address decoder, 8-1 muxes and a D type FF registers). The top design has 63 registers of different widths that can be written and read from with the Microblaze. The address decoder drives 1 enable line high to write to a register and to read a register, you drive the address decoders 6 select lines to a register. The design is kept pretty simple.

A serial terminal is used with the Uartlite to write values to a register and read from a register. The GPIO module has 23 outputs that connects as input to top module (16 data lines, 6 address lines and one write enable line). The Microblaze drives these lines to select a register, set the data to be written and toggle the write enable line.
There are 16 input lines from the top level back as inputs to the GPIO so the Microblaze can read a register by setting the address lines only and doing a GPIO read. All sounds good.

I have validated the block design and packaged the design as a HDL wrapper.

My issue appears during implementation and the fact the Vivado tools has a problem with the signals that connect between the GPIO module and the top RTL module. The errors I am getting after generating bitstream can be seen at the bottom.

What I don't understand is that these constraint errors (to me) seems like it complains that it doesn't know what voltage they run at and what package pin they connect to.

**For the first error** regarding the voltage standard, I can remove this error by going opening implementation, locating the aforementioned signals and changing the IO standard to CMOS3.3V. This then updates the constraints file (as I have commented out of constraints at bottom for completeness as I don't understand it fully) and removes the error? But why does the FPGA tools not know what voltage to port these signals at as they don't leave the chip?

**Regarding the second error,** I think it complains about not knowing a package pin on the FGA for these lines. But again these lines don't leave the FPGA package so why do we need to specify a location in the constraints file. Why can the tools not handle this? I don't understand this.

**EDIT**

When I look at the rstn_i line that it complains about, the tools has buffered it and connected it to 3.3V. But is has assigned it to package pin G17, which is in the constraints as vgaGreen[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Cgp.png) output line. Is this because the tools thinks this pin is spare as that line is commented out?

[image: rstn_i image]

**A final question,** why does the tools complain about the no ports matching sw15_reset_i switch that is on the board. It is marked as external on block design. Is this because it is not handled by a Vivado IP module which would take care of that?

Below is all the code, error messages etc.

Thanks to anyone who has the time to help!

**Errors Image**

[image: Errors Image]

**Block Diagram Image**

[image: Block Diagram Image]

**Hierarchy Image**

[image: Hierarchy Image]

**Top RTL**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity top is
  Port (clk_i                    : in std_logic;
        rstn_i                   : in std_logic;
        uBlaze_data_i            : in std_logic_vector(22 downto 0);
        reg_data_o               : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
       );
end top;

architecture Behavioral of top is

signal uBlaze_data_lines         : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal uBlaze_addr_lines         : std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);
signal uBlaze_wr_en_line         : std_logic;
signal reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines : std_logic_vector(63 downto 0);

type fault_times_reg_data is array (0 to 29) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal fault_times_data : fault_times_reg_data;

signal leds : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

type fault_types_reg_data is array (30 to 59) of std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
signal fault_types_data : fault_types_reg_data;

type fault_types_mux is array (30 to 59) of std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal fault_types_mux_data : fault_types_mux;

signal stuck_at_hold_time_reg_data : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
 
signal bit_flip_hold_time_reg_data : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0); 
signal bit_flip_hold_time_reg_mux  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

signal fault_injection_en_reg_data : std_logic_vector(0 downto 0);  
signal fault_injection_en_reg_mux  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);  

signal mux_zero_out  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_one_out   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_two_out   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_three_out : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_four_out  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_five_out  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_six_out   : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal mux_seven_out : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
signal read_mux_out  : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);

component Address_wr_Decoder is
  Port (clk_100MHz_i     : in std_logic;
        rstn_i           : in std_logic;
        uBlaze_wr_en_i   : in std_logic;
        uBlaze_addr_i    : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);     --6 bits of address input
        decoded_reg_en_o : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)    --64 bits of decoded register enable lines output
       );
end component;

component D_Type_FF_Reg is
generic(bit_width    : integer := 1);
  Port (clk_100MHz_i : in std_logic;
        rstn_i       : in std_logic;
        wr_en_i      : in std_logic;
        data_i       : in std_logic_vector(bit_width-1 downto 0);
        data_o       : out std_logic_vector(bit_width-1 downto 0)
       );
end component;

component eight_to_one_mux is
  Port (data_zero_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_one_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_two_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_three_i  : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_four_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_five_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_six_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_seven_i  : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        sel_i         : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        data_o        : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
       );
end component;

begin 

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- input and output mapping of microblaze input data to internal module signals ---

uBlaze_data_lines <= uBlaze_data_i(15 downto 0);
uBlaze_addr_lines <= uBlaze_data_i(21 downto 16);
uBlaze_wr_en_line <= uBlaze_data_i(22);

reg_data_o <= read_mux_out;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 6 to 64 bit address decoder component instantiation ---

Address_wr_Decoder_inst : Address_wr_Decoder
Port map (clk_100MHz_i     => clk_i,
          rstn_i           => rstn_i,
          uBlaze_wr_en_i   => uBlaze_wr_en_line,
          uBlaze_addr_i    => uBlaze_addr_lines,
          decoded_reg_en_o => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines
         );
  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 16-bit register component instantiations for fault times on 10 bits (30 off these) ---

Fault_Times_Regs_generate : for i in 0 to 29 generate

Fault_Times_Regs : D_Type_FF_Reg
 generic map (bit_width    => 16)
 Port map    (clk_100MHz_i => clk_i,
              rstn_i       => rstn_i,
              wr_en_i      => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines(i),
              data_i       => uBlaze_data_lines,
              data_o       => fault_times_data(i)
             );

end generate Fault_Times_Regs_generate;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 2-bit register component instantiations for fault types on 10 bits (30 off these) ---

Fault_Types_Regs_generate : for i in 30 to 59 generate

Fault_Types_Regs : D_Type_FF_Reg
 generic map (bit_width    => 2)
 Port map    (clk_100MHz_i => clk_i,
              rstn_i       => rstn_i,
              wr_en_i      => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines(i),
              data_i       => uBlaze_data_lines(1 downto 0),
              data_o       => fault_types_data(i)
             );

end generate Fault_Types_Regs_generate;

fault_types_mux_data(30) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(30);
fault_types_mux_data(31) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(31);
fault_types_mux_data(32) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(32);
fault_types_mux_data(33) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(33);
fault_types_mux_data(34) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(34);
fault_types_mux_data(35) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(35);
fault_types_mux_data(36) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(36);
fault_types_mux_data(37) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(37);
fault_types_mux_data(38) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(38);
fault_types_mux_data(39) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(39);
fault_types_mux_data(40) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(40);
fault_types_mux_data(41) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(41);
fault_types_mux_data(42) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(42);
fault_types_mux_data(43) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(43);
fault_types_mux_data(44) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(44);
fault_types_mux_data(45) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(45);
fault_types_mux_data(46) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(46);
fault_types_mux_data(47) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(47);
fault_types_mux_data(48) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(48);
fault_types_mux_data(49) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(49);
fault_types_mux_data(50) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(50);
fault_types_mux_data(51) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(51);
fault_types_mux_data(52) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(52);
fault_types_mux_data(53) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(53);
fault_types_mux_data(54) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(54);
fault_types_mux_data(55) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(55);
fault_types_mux_data(56) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(56);
fault_types_mux_data(57) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(57);
fault_types_mux_data(58) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(58);
fault_types_mux_data(59) <= "00000000000000" & fault_types_data(59);

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 16-bit register component instantiation for stuck at hold time (1 off these) ---

Stuck_at_Hold_Time_Reg : D_Type_FF_Reg
 generic map (bit_width    => 16)
 Port map    (clk_100MHz_i => clk_i,
              rstn_i       => rstn_i,
              wr_en_i      => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines(60),
              data_i       => uBlaze_data_lines,
              data_o       => stuck_at_hold_time_reg_data
             );

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 5-bit register component instantiation for bit flip hold time (1 off these) ---

Bit_Flip_Hold_Time_Reg : D_Type_FF_Reg
 generic map (bit_width    => 5)
 Port map    (clk_100MHz_i => clk_i,
              rstn_i       => rstn_i,
              wr_en_i      => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines(61),
              data_i       => uBlaze_data_lines(4 downto 0),
              data_o       => bit_flip_hold_time_reg_data
             );
             
bit_flip_hold_time_reg_mux(4 downto 0) <= bit_flip_hold_time_reg_data;
bit_flip_hold_time_reg_mux(15 downto 5) <= (others => '0');

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 1-bit register component instantiation for fault injection enable (1 off these) ---

Fault_Injection_Enable_Reg : D_Type_FF_Reg
 generic map (bit_width    => 1)
 Port map    (clk_100MHz_i => clk_i,
              rstn_i       => rstn_i,
              wr_en_i      => reg_addr_decoded_wr_lines(62),
              data_i       => uBlaze_data_lines(0 downto 0),
              data_o       => fault_injection_en_reg_data
             );
 
fault_injection_en_reg_mux(0 downto 0) <= fault_injection_en_reg_data;
fault_injection_en_reg_mux(15 downto 1) <= (others => '0');
            
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 0 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_0 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_times_data(0), 
          data_one_i    => fault_times_data(1), 
          data_two_i    => fault_times_data(2), 
          data_three_i  => fault_times_data(3), 
          data_four_i   => fault_times_data(4), 
          data_five_i   => fault_times_data(5), 
          data_six_i    => fault_times_data(6), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_times_data(7), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_zero_out 
       );

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 1 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_1 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_times_data(8), 
          data_one_i    => fault_times_data(9), 
          data_two_i    => fault_times_data(10), 
          data_three_i  => fault_times_data(11), 
          data_four_i   => fault_times_data(12), 
          data_five_i   => fault_times_data(13), 
          data_six_i    => fault_times_data(14), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_times_data(15), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_one_out 
       );

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 2 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_2 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_times_data(16), 
          data_one_i    => fault_times_data(17), 
          data_two_i    => fault_times_data(18), 
          data_three_i  => fault_times_data(19), 
          data_four_i   => fault_times_data(20), 
          data_five_i   => fault_times_data(21), 
          data_six_i    => fault_times_data(22), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_times_data(23), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_two_out 
       );
       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 3 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_3 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_times_data(24), 
          data_one_i    => fault_times_data(25), 
          data_two_i    => fault_times_data(26), 
          data_three_i  => fault_times_data(27), 
          data_four_i   => fault_times_data(28), 
          data_five_i   => fault_times_data(29), 
          data_six_i    => fault_types_mux_data(30), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_types_mux_data(31), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_three_out 
       );
       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 4 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_4 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_types_mux_data(32), 
          data_one_i    => fault_types_mux_data(33), 
          data_two_i    => fault_types_mux_data(34), 
          data_three_i  => fault_types_mux_data(35), 
          data_four_i   => fault_types_mux_data(36), 
          data_five_i   => fault_types_mux_data(37), 
          data_six_i    => fault_types_mux_data(38), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_types_mux_data(39), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_four_out 
       );
       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 5 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_5 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_types_mux_data(40), 
          data_one_i    => fault_types_mux_data(41), 
          data_two_i    => fault_types_mux_data(42), 
          data_three_i  => fault_types_mux_data(43), 
          data_four_i   => fault_types_mux_data(44), 
          data_five_i   => fault_types_mux_data(45), 
          data_six_i    => fault_types_mux_data(46), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_types_mux_data(47), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_five_out 
       );          

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 6 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_6 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_types_mux_data(48), 
          data_one_i    => fault_types_mux_data(49), 
          data_two_i    => fault_types_mux_data(50), 
          data_three_i  => fault_types_mux_data(51), 
          data_four_i   => fault_types_mux_data(52), 
          data_five_i   => fault_types_mux_data(53), 
          data_six_i    => fault_types_mux_data(54), 
          data_seven_i  => fault_types_mux_data(55), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_six_out 
       ); 
       
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 7 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_7 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => fault_types_mux_data(56), 
          data_one_i    => fault_types_mux_data(57), 
          data_two_i    => fault_types_mux_data(58), 
          data_three_i  => fault_types_mux_data(59), 
          data_four_i   => stuck_at_hold_time_reg_data, 
          data_five_i   => bit_flip_hold_time_reg_mux, 
          data_six_i    => fault_injection_en_reg_mux, 
          data_seven_i  => (others => '0'), 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(2 downto 0), 
          data_o        => mux_seven_out 
       );    

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--- 8 to 1 mux 8 component instantiation ---

eight_to_one_mux_inst_8 : eight_to_one_mux 
Port map (data_zero_i   => mux_zero_out, 
          data_one_i    => mux_one_out, 
          data_two_i    => mux_two_out, 
          data_three_i  => mux_three_out, 
          data_four_i   => mux_four_out, 
          data_five_i   => mux_five_out, 
          data_six_i    => mux_six_out, 
          data_seven_i  => mux_seven_out, 
          sel_i         => uBlaze_addr_lines(5 downto 3), 
          data_o        => read_mux_out 
       );   
             
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------     
                              
end Behavioral;
```

**Address wr Decoder RTL**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Address_wr_Decoder is
  Port (clk_100MHz_i     : in std_logic;
        rstn_i           : in std_logic;
        uBlaze_wr_en_i   : in std_logic;
        uBlaze_addr_i    : in std_logic_vector(5 downto 0);     --6 bits of address input
        decoded_reg_en_o : out std_logic_vector(63 downto 0)    --64 bits of decoded register enable lines output
       );
end Address_wr_Decoder;

architecture Behavioral of Address_wr_Decoder is

begin

Decoder_Process : Process (clk_100MHz_i, rstn_i)

begin

if (rstn_i = '0') then
    decoded_reg_en_o <= (others => '0');
    
elsif (rising_edge(clk_100MHz_i)) then
    if (uBlaze_wr_en_i = '1') then
        decoded_reg_en_o <= (others => '0'); 
        decoded_reg_en_o(to_integer(unsigned(uBlaze_addr_i))) <= '1';
    
    else
        decoded_reg_en_o <= (others => '0');
        
    end if;
end if;

end Process;

end Behavioral;
```

**D Type FF RTL**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity D_Type_FF_Reg is
generic(bit_width    : integer := 1);
  Port (clk_100MHz_i : in std_logic;
        rstn_i       : in std_logic;
        wr_en_i      : in std_logic;
        data_i       : in std_logic_vector(bit_width-1 downto 0);
        data_o       : out std_logic_vector(bit_width-1 downto 0)
       );
end D_Type_FF_Reg;

architecture Behavioral of D_Type_FF_Reg is

signal data_temp : std_logic_vector(bit_width-1 downto 0);

begin

Reg_Process : Process (clk_100MHz_i, rstn_i)

begin

if (rstn_i = '0') then
    data_temp <= (others => '0');
    
elsif (rising_edge(clk_100MHz_i)) then
    
    if (wr_en_i = '1') then
        data_temp <= data_i;
    
    end if;
end if;

end Process;

data_o <= data_temp;

end Behavioral;
```

**8-1 Mux RTL**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity eight_to_one_mux is
  Port (data_zero_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_one_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_two_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_three_i  : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_four_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_five_i   : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_six_i    : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        data_seven_i  : in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        sel_i         : in std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
        data_o        : out std_logic_vector(15 downto 0)
       );
end eight_to_one_mux;

architecture Behavioral of eight_to_one_mux is

begin

with sel_i select
data_o <= data_zero_i  when "000",
          data_one_i   when "001",
          data_two_i   when "010",
          data_three_i when "011",
          data_four_i  when "100",
          data_five_i  when "101",
          data_six_i   when "110",
          data_seven_i when others;
  
end Behavioral;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the GPIO module is implicitly designed to connect directly to chip pins only. (I believe it instantiates the IO buffers internally.) I've used it before, but only for that purpose -- not to connect to internal logic. For internal registers, etc., I've always used either the BRAM controller or EPC (external peripheral controller) modules.

Comment: For the record, I don't agree with the close vote. There's a lot of data, but only one question.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks for responding. You seem to be correct with AXI GPIO being intended only for IO porting. This makes sense why the tools attempt to assign the signals to IO port buffers and package pins. Also when this design worked for me, the IO used went directly to switches and LEDs on the board, which explains why it works as they went to IO ports anyway.

Comment: @David777 This site isn't really for putting projects on, there are limits on size for the questions and answers, since we need to follow the format of the site can you please store the files somewhere else and link to them? Git would be a solution.